# using ComboBox.SelectedItem to change the selected item works for one set of ComboBoxes, but fails on another

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
     private void SetGridComboBoxSelectedItems(Grid Matrix, List<ComboBoxItem> SelectedItemsList)
    {
        foreach(Border item in Matrix.Children)
        {
            ComboBox box = item.Child as ComboBox;

            if(box != null)
            {
                //This works correctly and isn't the problem
                int index = GridItemToIndex(box.Parent as UIElement, Matrix.RowDefinitions.Count - 1, 2, Matrix.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1, 1)

                //This is the Line that is hit or miss
                box.SelectedItem = SelectedItemsList[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

So this function works for one set of ComboBoxes that are inside of a grid but not another even though both sets are almost identical and get sent through the same functions up to this point.

The SelectedItemsList is pulled from the same source that populates the comboboxes themselves, so I am at a bit of a loss on what I need to do here.

Comment: are you doing this in 'code behind' or a ViewModel? ideally, you'll want to do this in a ViewModel via binding.

Comment: No the source is being set in the back end but I just received the project and it's too integrated to fix at the moment.